# Unable to get response of root - laravel testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, laravel-4

I have my htaccess set up to redirect `'/'` requests to `/newTheme/#/dashboard/` 
so the root is no more `laravel/public/`.

Now when I call home page from a test case, it gets response for `laravel/public` while I need the response for `/newTheme/#/dashboard/`

Test Method:

```
public function testDashboard()
    {
        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/');
        $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isOk());
    }
```

How can I get the response for the root ?

I tried with `../../newTheme/index.php/dashboard/` but did not work.